# How to invoke a C# web service through PHP?

Tags: c#, php, web-services, nusoap

I've written a web service using ASP.NET (in C#) and I'm attempting to write an example PHP client using NuSOAP.  Where I'm tripped up on are examples of how to do this; some show `soapval` being used (and I don't quite understand the parameters - for example passing `false` as `string` types, etc.), while others are just using straight `array`s.  Let's say the WSDL for my web service as reported by `http://localhost:3333/Service.asmx?wsdl` looks something like:

```
POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/webservices/DoSomething"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <DoSomething xmlns="http://tempuri.org/webservices">
      <anId>int</anId>
      <action>string</action>
      <parameters>
        <Param>
          <Value>string</Value>
          <Name>string</Name>
        </Param>
        <Param>
          <Value>string</Value>
          <Name>string</Name>
        </Param>
      </parameters>
    </DoSomething>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My first PHP attempt looks like:

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost:3333/Service.asmx?wsdl');

$params = array(
    'anId' => 3, //new soapval('anId', 'int', 3),
    'action' => 'OMNOMNOMNOM',
    'parameters' => array(
        'firstName' => 'Scott',
        'lastName' => 'Smith'
    )
);
$result = $client->call('DoSomething', $params, 'http://tempuri.org/webservices/DoSomething', 'http://tempuri.org/webservices/DoSomething');
print_r($result);
?>
```

Now aside from the Param type being a complex type which I'm pretty sure my simple `$array` attempt will not automagically work with, I'm breakpointing in my web service and seeing the method I've marked as `WebMethod` (without renaming it, its literally `DoSomething`) and seeing the arguments are all default values (the `int` is `0`, the `string` is `null`, etc.).

What should my PHP syntax look like, and what do I have to do to pass the `Param` type correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wrap things in tons of nested arrays.

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost:3333/Service.asmx?wsdl');

$params = array(
      'anId' => 3,
      'action' => 'OMNOMNOMNOM',
      'parameters' => array(
              'Param' => array(
                  array('Name' => 'firstName', 'Value' => 'Scott'),
                  array('Name' => 'lastName', 'Value' => 'Smith')
                       )
      )
);
$result = $client->call('DoSomething', array($params), 
                'http://tempuri.org/webservices/DoSomething', 
                'http://tempuri.org/webservices/DoSomething');
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've taken a dislike to PHP after this experience.

Comment: Really? You blame PHP for one 3rd-party library?  That's like taking a dislike for ice cream after having eating bad butterscotch.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of unrelated but since PHP5 you have native support for SOAP.

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");
$client->DoSomething($params);
```

That might be a little more convenient.

http://se.php.net/soap

Answer (score 1):

Here the sample with native SOAP support:

```
    // Create a new soap client based on the service's metadata (WSDL)
    $client = new SoapClient("http://some.wsdl",
        array('location' => 'http://127.0.0.100:80/IntegrationService/php'));

    $params = array();
    $params['lead']['Firstname']    = $user->firstname;
    $params['lead']['Lastname']     = $user->lastname;
    $params['lead']['Product']      = $product;
    $params['lead']['JobTitle']     = $user->job_title;
    $params['lead']['Email']        = $user->mail;
    $params['lead']['Phone']        = $user->phone;
    $params['lead']['CompanyName']  = $user->company_name;
    $params['lead']['City']         = $user->city;
    $params['lead']['Industry']     = $user->industry;

    $client->SubmitLead($params);
```

Where '.../IntegrationService/php' in SoapClient description is endpoint in WCF:

```
<endpoint
            address="php"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="Integration.Service.IDrupalIntegrationService" />
```